# How to programmatically reload MVC Application project at run time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, codedom

I am creating some classes by `C#` `CodeDOM`, in run time.  then i include cs files that i created by `CodeDOM` in my project like this:

```
var p = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(@"D:\imanSal\SmlpeApp\SmlpeApp\SmlpeApp.csproj");
p.AddItem("Compile", outputFileName + this.ClassName + ".cs");
p.Save();
p.Build();
```

Then im getting a **File Modification detected**  warning because my project has been modified outside the environment, so I have to reload it.
What must I do if I want to Reload my project programmatically in run time? what's the best solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could include additional files to compile by specify them in the project file. For example, put dynamic creating file to Lib folder, then you can add this code to your project file `(<Compile Include="Lib\*.cs" />),` after that these files will be included during the build.

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Class1.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Lib\*.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The file modification detected waring is the feature of Visual Studio, so there isn’t the way to load the project programmatically through MSBuild.

Comment: thanks ...you pushed me  forward but my main  problem is still exist.  ...can you give me any solution about re compiling project (when some changes were happen) in iis?

Comment: or any solution for update dlls ? or  what ever way which can solve my problem ?

Comment: @ImanSalehi Your code is ok, just remove p.AddItem and p.Save.

Comment: i did ...and it worked...but i think my iis need to recycle the apppool(or some think like that) because the changes (which i did with code dom) will implement in project( dlls), only when the project stop and run again ...my problem is this

Comment: @ImanSalehi The application pool need to be recycled if the app has been compiled, there isn't the way to prevent it.

Comment: oh ...i knew ....unfortunately your solution was not working yet ...i added  "<Compile Include="Myclass name .cs" /> "  in a file named "projectname.pubXml" but my class was not build in run time by this solution ...can you say me where i have to write this piece of code in?????

Comment: @ImanSalehi The code should be in your project file (e.g. .csproj) instead of pub.xml file.